MERN Stack: Failed to parse user from cookies
I used mongo db for login and jwt token in authorization.
The Login response:
{_id: '666d30899f2bb9bfc3d5978d', name: 'demo', email: 'demo@example.com', token: adfasdfsdfasf}

I can log in with email and password by Login.jsx page
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [, setCookie] = useCookies(["user"]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/login",
        {
          email,
          password,
        }
      );

      console.log("Login response:", response.data);

      // Set user info in a cookie as a JSON string
      setCookie("user", JSON.stringify(response.data), { path: "/" });

      // Navigate to the department list
      navigate("/departments");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Login error:", err);
      setError("Invalid email or password");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
        <div>
          <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
            Sign in to your account
          </h2>
        </div>
        <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {error && (
            <div className="rounded-md bg-red-50 p-4">
              <div className="flex">
                <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                  <svg
                    className="h-5 w-5 text-red-400"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      fillRule="evenodd"
                      d="M10 3a1 1 0 00-.707.293l-7 7a1 1 0 000 1.414l7 7a1 1 0 001.414-1.414L4.414 11H17a1 1 0 100-2H4.414l4.293-4.293A1 1 0 0010 3z"
                      clipRule="evenodd"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div className="ml-3">
                  <h3 className="text-sm font-medium text-red-800">{error}</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="email-address" className="sr-only">
                Email address
              </label>
              <input
                id="email-address"
                name="email"
                type="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                required
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Email address"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                required
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <input
                id="remember-me"
                name="remember-me"
                type="checkbox"
                className="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
              />
              <label
                htmlFor="remember-me"
                className="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900"
              >
                Remember me
              </label>
            </div>

            <div className="text-sm">
              <a
                href="#"
                className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
              >
                Forgot your password?
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
            >
              Sign in
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

But in the Navbar the user information does not show. In the console it shows "Failed to parse user from cookies" SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
Here is the Navbar.jsx :
import React from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [cookies, , removeCookie] = useCookies(["user"]);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    // Clear user info from cookies
    removeCookie("user", { path: "/" });

    // Redirect to login page
    navigate("/login");
  };

  // Retrieve user info from cookies
  let user = null;
  try {
    if (cookies.user) {
      user = JSON.parse(cookies.user);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to parse user from cookies:", error);
  }

  console.log("User from cookies:", user);

  return (
    <div className="max-w-screen-2xl container mx-auto">
      <div className="navbar bg-base-100 shadow-md">
        <div className="navbar-start">
          {/* Dropdown and logo */}
          <a className="btn btn-ghost text-xl">BMS</a>
        </div>
        <div className="navbar-center hidden lg:flex">
          {/* Main menu */}
          <ul className="menu menu-horizontal px-1">
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li tabIndex={0}>
              <details>
                <summary>HR & Payroll</summary>
                <ul className="p-2 bg-base-100 shadow-md">
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/settings">Settings</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/employee">Employee Information</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </details>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="hidden md:block">
          {/* Search bar */}
          <label className="input input-bordered flex items-center gap-2">
            <input type="text" className="grow" placeholder="Search" />
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
              fill="currentColor"
              className="w-4 h-4 opacity-70"
            >
              <path
                fillRule="evenodd"
                d="M9.965 11.026a5 5 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.755 2.754a.75.75 0 1 1-1.06 1.06l-2.755-2.754ZM10.5 7a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 7 0Z"
                clipRule="evenodd"
              />
            </svg>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="navbar-end flex items-center gap-4">
          {user ? (
            <div className="flex flex-col items-end">
              <span className="text-sm text-gray-700">{user.email}</span>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="flex flex-col items-end">
              <span className="text-sm text-gray-700">
                User information not available
              </span>
            </div>
          )}
          {/* Logout button */}
          <button className="btn" onClick={handleLogout}>
            Logout
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

What is the reason and what is the best standard of Login.

Is it normal to have 2 commas in the line with useCookies(["user"])?

Please specify which line is throwing the error.

@ray, I removed extra comma. But nothing happend.
